# Perl: Group input data by first field

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have a data file that contains an interface name and destination.  I want to group all destinations by interface so that I can iterate through and store results.  Here is an example of my output:

```
eth0,1.1.1.1
eth0,1.1.1.2
eth1,1.1.1.1
eth1,1.1.1.2
```

How do i dump the unique interface values into a hash and build an array of destinations?

Comment: `split(/,/)` is a good start...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my %ifs;

while ( my $line = <STDIN> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my ( $iface, $destination ) = split /,/, $line;
    push @{ $ifs{ $iface } }, $destination;
}
```

Should work.

Comment: Thank you!! I knew i was over complicating things.